# Python, Extract spline coefficient

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, spline

I am using python3, Scipy

I have a 3d points (x,y,z]
From them I make s apline using [scipy.interpolate.splprep](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splprep.html)

```
x_points = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 10)
y_points = np.sin(x_points)
z_points = np.cos(x_points)
path = np.vstack([x_points, y_points, z_points])
tck, u = sc.splprep(path, k=3, s=0)
```

I wish to get the coefficients of the spline[i]:
For example the latest splins:
sp9 = a9 + b9(x-x4) + c9(x-x4)^2 + d9(x-x4)^3

I know that the [tck](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splprep.html) is (t,c,k) a tuple containing the vector of knots, the B-spline coefficients, and the degree of the spline.
But I don't see how I can get this spline function and plot only it

Answer (score 0):

The coefficients in the `tck` tuple are in the b-spline basis. If you want to convert them to the power basis, you can do `PPoly.from_spline(tck)` .
An obligatory note however: converting between bases incurs numerical errors.

EDIT. First, as it's splprep, you'll need to convert the list-of-arrays `c` into a proper numpy array and transpose (it's a known wart of splPrep). Then, as it turns out, PPoly.from_spline does not handle multidimensional `c` (this might be a nice pull request to the scipy repository), so you'll need to e.g. loop over the dimensions. Something along the lines of (continuing from your OP)

```
t, c, k = tck
cc = np.asarray(c)    # cc.shape is (3, 10) now
spl0 = sc.PPoly.from_spline((t, cc.T[0], k))
print(spl0.c)   # here are your coefficients for the component 0
```

Comment: usign `p = sc.PPoly.from_spline(tck)` i got this error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'`

Comment: Ah, splprep. Need to transpose the c array then

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that

Comment: There is still something that I miss. The dimension of spl0.c don't make sense to me: `spl0.c.shape: (4, 13)`. Can you please give an example of how to extract the x,y,z point of the first and second polynom (there should be 9 polynomials in total since I used 10 points in x_points var: `x_points = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 10)`)

Comment: For the meaning of PPoly coefficients, you just best read up in the PPoly docs

Comment: It just dont make sense. `tck:t` is the vector of knots: how can the first values be the same? you wrote that `spl0 = sc.PPoly.from_spline((t, cc.T[0], k)) contains the coefficients for the component 0`, its dimension is (4,13) - the number of rows is the 4 coefficient ? but the number of columns is 13, why?...... For each spline there should be 4 coefficients for s_y(x) and 4 coefficients for s_z(x), it doesn't show that it the documentation. I Would appreciate it if you could explain this too

Comment: This is a standard thing: you need the knot vector to be k-regular for b-splines of degree k. Like I said, this is something you'd need to read up. One source could be Lyche and Morkem lecture notes, listed in the docstring of BSpline.

Comment: maybe then it's not a standard thing, and there something complicated that needed to be explained by the group that developed this package? In any case, this problem didn't resolve so far.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using this method:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as sc

x_points = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 10)
y_points = np.sin(x_points)
z_points = np.cos(x_points)
path = np.vstack([x_points, y_points, z_points])
tck, u = sc.splprep(path, k=3, s=0)

p = sc.PPoly.from_spline(tck)
```

but I'm getting this error on the last line:

> p = sc.PPoly.from_spline(tck) File
> "C:\Users...\Python38\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py",
> line 1314, in from_spline cvals = np.empty((k + 1, len(t)-1),
> dtype=c.dtype)
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'